# ¿Como se puede desactivar el ajuste automatico de una region en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Estoy trabajando en C# con Visual Studio Community y estoy ocupando regiones, cuando escribo una linea dentro de esa region es desajusta la identacion que le pongo, habra alguna forma de desactivarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Podrias ir a las opciones de configuracion del visual studio `Tools->Options`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cambiando la cantidad de tabs se se aplican o anulandolo